# Access VSAM file using Python?

Tags: python-3.8, mainframe, zos

Is it possible to access VSAM datasets of mainframe using Python 3.8 in ZOS? I tried accessing vsam simple file in python 2.7 just like ps files. That seemed to be working. When i tried same in 3.8. It is not able to even read simple PS file data.
Code:

```
import codecs                                      
f = open("//'VSAM file name'",'r')  
f1=codecs.getreader('cp1047_oe')(f)                
for line in f1:                                    
    print line,                                    
print (f1)                                         
print ("Read record is :", f)                      
f.close()
```

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: The file not found However the vsam file does exist in mainframe. Even then the error message is "File is not found".

Answer (score 1):

For trying to work with datasets there is a helpful blog entry that oulines the process:
[Using IBM Open Enterprise Python for z/OS and ZOAU to Work With Datasets](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ibmz-and-linuxone/blogs/austin-wells1/2020/12/11/using-ibm-open-enterprise-python-for-zos-and-zoau)

You will need to have the zoau binary along with having to install the zoautil_py python package. The instructions are available on their [KC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKFYE_1.0.3/welcome_zoautil.html) in the [install](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKFYE_1.0.3/install.html) section.

**Note:** There my be version changes from when the blog was published. I am using the zoau version `V1.1.0` and there are some API call changes when compared to the blog, e.g. `zoautil_py.Datasets` is now `zoautil_py.datasets`. It would be preferable to use the latest stable version available.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will install Zoau utilities and try with those option. I will update if that works.